# Check for database records every few seconds

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have Delphi 10.1 and Firebird 3 database, I need to check for new record every 2-3 seconds and display on the main screen.

Currently I am using a timer which checks for new records on net database after every 3 seconds and display in the form if new records are available in the database/table.

but this is not the right way to perform the task, what is best practice for continues checking database records.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can write an insertion trigger and post a [**database event**](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/papers_presentations/Power_Firebird_events.pdf) from there. For client implementation with FireDAC see the [**Database Alerts**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Database_Alerts_(FireDAC)) topic.